# dump files maxing C drive with corrupt mdf

Tags: sql-server

I have some databases with corrupt mdf and my C dive on the SQL server is getting maxed out with error dump files,

I am not asking how to troubleshoot why  these files are being created, I already know what the problem is, why they are being created and what I need to do to correct the underlying issue.

what I would like to know is how to prevent or limit the creation and retention of these dump files so they don't max out my C drive while I am doing repairs

thanks

Comment: If you are not planning to use the dump files, schedule a PowerShell script to delete them.  Or you could try the suggestion I made in your other question about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should limit your error log size. According to [support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2199578), you can accomplish this by executing on the target instance the following script:

```
USE [master];
GO

EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
    N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer',
    N'ErrorLogSizeInKb', REG_DWORD, 5120;
GO
```

Another thing you might want to check is where you have your TempDB stored. If it's on C drive, than perhaps you should move it to another drive.

If you'te getting memory minidumps due to crashes of the database engine, than you should follow Dan Guzman's suggestion and create a script to move or delete them.